# an event listener on a feed created through EventSource in javascript

Tags: javascript, playframework, apache-kafka

I have created a function in JavaScript in which I have created a feed through

```
var feed = new EventSource("@routes.HomeController.kafkaStream");
```

and then added a listener on it through

```
feed.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    $('#messages').append("<pre>" + event.data + "</pre>");
}
```

Through this I am able to see the output in the div tag with id ="messages" but when I use another browser in another computer I am not able to see the output i.e. I am able to see the output in only 1 browser and that too sometimes disappear. 
All this is implemented in html file of play framework.

Comment: I found out the solution, problem was with my kafka-stream

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we have to use different client-ids for each browser or else you won't be able to see it on all browser.

Generate a random number for each client to show it in all browsers

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.